# How do I mock Spring ApplicationContext's getBean method using Mockito for writing unit tests with TestNG?

Tags: java, spring, mockito, testng

I am writing unit tests for the following class

Class to Be Tested:

```
public class RandomManager {
        @Autowired
        private ApplicationContext context;

        @Autowired
        private ClassA objectA;

        public void methodToBeTested() {
            objectA.methodToBeVerified(context.getBean(Random.class,"Yaswanth","Yaswanth"));
        }
    }
```

Below is the test class:

```
public class RandomManagerTest {

    @Mock
    private ClassA objectA;

    @Mock
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @InjectMocks
    private RandomManager randomManager;

    @BeforeTest
    public void before() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        doReturn(any(Random.class)).when(context)
            .getBean(any(Class.class), any(), any());
    }

    @Test
    public void methodToBeTestedTest() {
        Random randomObject = new RandomObject("Yaswanth", "Yaswanth");
        randomManager.methodToBeTested();
        verify(objectA).methodToBeVerified(randomObject);
    }
}
```

The above code fails in the before method when I am trying to stub the
applicationContext mock. I get the following error.

> You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
>   Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
>      when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
>      doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());
>       verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))
>
> This message may appear after an NullPointerException if the last
>   matcher is returning an object  like any() but the stubbed method
>   signature expect a primitive argument, in this case, use primitive
>   alternatives.
>       when(mock.get(any())); // bad use, will raise NPE
>       when(mock.get(anyInt())); // correct usage use
>
> Also, this error might show up because you use argument matchers with
>   methods that cannot be mocked. Following methods *cannot* be
>   stubbed/verified: final/private/equals()/hashCode(). Mocking methods
>   declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.

Can anyone please help me understand what am I doing wrong in the
above code?

Note: I am using TestNG and Mockito. I can extend
`AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests` and use a `spring-test.xml`, declare my
beans and autowire applicationContext. I feel that is an overkill for
my use case. I need to just mock applicationContext's getBean method.

Comment: Apologies for the formatting. I haven't been able to submit the question for some weird reason. Hence the  ugly format.

Comment: I don't really understand why you would mock anything in Spring based test (except maybe the http layer using MockMVC).  When you use `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` you can load all you spring beans, and they will be wired together, and you test the actual code, rather than stubs that return something defined in the test, and never actually execute the code inside dependent beans. Mocking is a great tool when used right, but I have never used it for Spring based test, and when I have seen others do it, it has always been a mess.

Comment: I think @KlausGroenbaek is correct. Instead of trying to mock the Spring ApplicationContext, use it. Create a test application context that returns the appropriate beans / mocks as needed for your test.

Comment: @KlausGroenbaek `@RunWith` is not available with TestNG and `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests` should be used instead.

Comment: You are right, I forgot it was TestNG. I prefer JUnit with Spring, as it is just better integrated. Although there are some features like parameterized tests that are easier in TestNG. There is a paradigme difference between the two, because each JUnit test is run on a new instance of the Test class, where TestNG reuses the same instance for multiple tests, so you have to be careful if you use local variables.

Comment: @MichaelPeacock I am trying to write unit tests and I am creating mocks for spring beans. I don't want to use SpringContext as I specified in the Note section of the question.

Comment: @KlausGroenbaek If I create a spring context and load all the spring beans, how will I test the functionality specfic to one class unless I have a way of separating the class to be tested from rest of the code base? Mockito makes it possible for me in this case by creating mocks and stubbing their methods.

Comment: If class A depends on class B, then you should test them together. In Spring rather than mocking B, I would implement a production and a test version of the bean, because if I refactor the way A uses B, then I will also change the test version of B. One of the issues with Mocking is that you tend to only mock the methods on B that A is currently using, so when you refactor you code, your mock test break. I have seen a lof of mock test that basically duplicate the current logic inside the bean you are trying to test. User Spring profiles and test implementation of your interfaces instead!

Comment: When I refactor A, I have to make sure that the existing functionality is unaffected and if I am changing some existing functionality without my knowledge, these unit tests will stop me right there. I agree that we may write some redundant code with tests. I think spring tests will fall under integration testing or system testing IMO. I am also new to testing so cannot say for sure what the right approach is!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue comes from `doReturn(any(Random.class))` where you are not allowed to use `any()`.
Just replace it by a real instance.

Comment: Thanks @juherr. It worked. But why are we not supposed to use any() in doReturn()?

Comment: I suppose because any* id for param matching, not for the returned param. In fact, the solution was in the error message. But maybe what you'd like could be possible (a good new SO question)